# How does the pointwise ergodic theorem generalize the strong law of large numbers?

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory

I've heard (e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)) that the pointwise ergodic theorem (PWET) generalizes the strong law of large numbers (SLLN). **How exactly does the PWET generalize the SLLN?** The PWET requires a measure-preserving (and ergodic for a stronger conclusion) transformation. **What is the measure preserving (and maybe ergodic) transformation in the SLLN?**

I've also heard it said (though I don't recall where) that the PWET's generalization of the the SLLN is essentially because the PWET only requires "independence in the limit", whereas the SLLN requires the sequence to be i.i.d. **What is meant by "independence in the limit"?**

Comment: To complete @GEdgar's answer, let me mention that in a probabilistic context, independence in the limit means that the asymptotic sigma-algebra is trivial (this is the so-called Kolmogorov zero-one law). By the way, the strong law of large numbers holds in a much wider context than the i.i.d. case.

Comment: @DidierPiau Thanks. What is the "asymptotic sigma-algebra"?

Comment: The sigma-algebra of [tail events](http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/TailEvent.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be a probability distribution on $\mathbb R$.  Consider the product space $\Omega := \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \dots$ with product measure $P = \mu \times \mu \times \dots\;$.  Let $f : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ be the "first component" map, $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) = x_1$.  Let $T : \Omega \to \Omega$ be the "left shift" map, $T(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) = (x_2,x_3,\dots)\;\;$.  Then (1) $T$ is a measure-preserving transformation, and (2) on the sample space $\Omega$ with respect to the measure $P$, the sequence $X_n(\omega) = f(T^n(\omega))\;$ is an i.i.d. sequence of random variables with distribution $\mu$.  The strong law of large numbers and the individual ergodic theorem both tell us about a.s. convergence of
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n X_j
$$
subject to certain conditions.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand your answer, and hence consider my first two questions answered. What about my last question regarding the meaning of "independence in the limit"?

Comment: How about $\Omega\neq \mathbb{R}^\infty$?